# Quantum operator order

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, momentum, wavefunction, phase-space

I have the following quantum mechanical Hamiltonian that the professor wrote down in class:

$$H = p^2 q + q^2p - pq.$$

He asked us to apply this to a wavefunction: $\Psi(q)$. I know that we define $$p = -i \hbar \partial / \partial q. $$

I am getting confused as to how to formally apply now, $H \Psi(q)$, since, the first term, for example would give:

$$H = (-\partial^2 / \partial q^2)q \Psi,$$ and so on...

In other words, what exactly is $$(-\partial^2 / \partial q^2)q~?$$

Comment: simply take two derivatives of $(q\Psi)$ and apply the usual product rule for derivatives.

Comment: Hi @ZeroTheHero . So, it is not $-\partial^2 / \partial q^2$ applied to q first, giving zero?

Comment: No.  It is applies to the product. $q$ multiplies $\Psi$ so the resulting state is $\Psi'=q\Psi$.  The operator $p^2$ sees the state $\Psi'$.

Comment: @Countto10 Thanks for that. But, I think this Hamiltonian is already Hermitian, because of the pq term.?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Okay. Thanks for that. Is this Hamiltonian already Hermitian? I was trying to see if Countto10's link would apply?

Comment: @ThomasMoore I actually don't think so but you would have to check carefully.

Comment: Zero knows more than I do, so please follow his comments. But, one thing I would say is, when classical equations are converted to quantum equivalents, (the old name was quantum prescription) that ordering may matter and later on you may have to deal with this aspect. You might ask your professor about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is

$$-\frac{\partial}{\partial q}\left(\frac{\partial}{ \partial q}\left(q \Psi(q)\right)\right)$$

which is

$$-\frac{\partial}{\partial q} \left( \Psi(q) + q \Psi'(q)\right)$$

where $$\Psi'(q) = \frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial q}$$

You can take it from there.